# How to pass any object from master to workers in Node.js?

Tags: node.js

I would like to create an object in TypeScript that will be used by every worker. Example:

```
if (cluster.isMaster)
// create object foo: Foo
```

I want to use the same instance of Foo class in all workers. Example:

```
if (cluster.isWorker)
// use foo object created in master
```

How can I achieve that? Note that *foo* **cannot be serialized** to JSON. I've tried with worker.send(message_with_object) in *master* and process.on('message' object) in *worker* but it hasn't worked (the object has to be stringified).

Comment: I don't think you can. What is it that you're trying to send anyway?

Comment: you can pass file/socket handles between node processes, but everything else has to be serialized. https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_send_message_sendhandle_options_callback